# Is there any method to identify if the rotation animation is limited to a single plane from the quaternioins

Tags: 3d, rotation, quaternions

I have quaternion values for different time frames for a rotation animation.
Is there any method to identify if the rotation is limited to a single plane from the quaternion values?

Answer (score 3):

well, quaternions represent rotation around an axis, so the rotation is in the plane orthogonal to this axis, no ?

Comment: I have qauternions for each time frame. The entire rotation should be in the same plane. I am looking for any relation between these qauternions to compute the plane of rotation.

Comment: each rotation should be in the same planes ?

Comment: The normal of the "plane of rotation" is defined by the vector component of the quaternion. However where that plane is positioned in 3D space cannot be expressed with just a single quaternion. If you know the plane normal then together with some information from your application you may be able to determine the position of the plane.